# AWS lambda serverless image handler sign-url not working getting NoSuchKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

Trying to resize image on the fly by using AWS lambda serverless image Handler, CloudFront .

Acutally I want to get this feature by using CloudFormation.
I have already a s3 bucket and i want that set that bucket for cloudFront that thing i can not work getting face problem with that.

I have found a template for serverless Image Handler on cloudFormation to created stack by using that template when stack was created then i have seen new bucket create with I AM user which i do not want .

I want that create stack with existing S3 Bucket.
After stack created i see that when i use >>> {
  /fit-in/230x230/
getting error like 
`NoSuchKey`
The specified key does not exist.
not work with this url:

**https://{cloudFrontUrl}/fit-in/230x230/app/gold-pack-osclass-pack.jpg**

and work with this url:

**https://{cloudFrontUrl}/app/gold-pack-osclass-pack.jpg.**

this template I have used for creatiug stack on cloudFormation from this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/serverless-image-handler/latest/serverless-image-handler.pdf) on page No 7 and choose the link download the template .